# How to query object by NSDate property correctly in Realm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, realm

I have the following scenario, I store an object on Realm with current date, like this:

```c
RLMChatMessage *chat = [[RLMChatMessage alloc] init];
chat.chatFrom = from;
chat.chatTo = to;
chat.timeStamp = [NSDate date];

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock: ^{
      [realm addObject: chat];
}];
```

To send the timestamp to the server, I convert it to NSString as follows:

```c
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:  @"YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS”]; // Capital ’S’ is milliseconds
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
return [dateFormat stringFromDate: date];
```

The result of the timestamp in NSString is: 20190612090741181 with format of "YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS”.

When I receive an acknowledge message for the specific timestamp, I convert the NSString back to NSDate:

```c
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS”];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
return [dateFormat dateFromString: strTime];
```

I than query the chat with timestamp (NSDate object created with the above code) as follows:

```c
RLMResults *results = [RLMChatMessage objectsWhere:@"timeStamp == %@", date];
return results.firstObject;
```

Sadly enough, the results has NO objects found. Somehow, Realm can’t seem to find the chat object with provided NSDate timestamp.
Using Realm Browser app to look in the database, I can see the NSDate property with the following NSDate:
[image]

The NSLog output in Xcode for converting NSString timestamp to NSDate looks like this:
[image]

So both show the NSDate timestamp the same. I assume both print the NSDate object to local time of my machine. So, how come Realm can’t find the chat object? I’m kind of lost in here. Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: *To send the timestamp to the server, I convert it to NSString as follows:* why? Also, if you are converting to a string to stored on the server, it looks like it's a Date object in your screenshot, not a string. Can you clarify?

Comment: The converted string is: 20190612090741181 that is sent to the server, which is UTC time in the following format: YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS. Anyway, on the last screenshot you can see that converting 20190612090741181 (UTC) time to NSDate object is correct. The NSLog output is the same as that is stored in Realm database. But still can't programmatically get that model object by timeStamp from the Realm database.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. A date is a date. There's no reason to jump through the hoops of converting it to a string for saving and back. Just store it as a Date object in Realm. Oh, and Realm stores date objects in the following format `2019-06-13T14:25:04.433Z`

Comment: Not sure what this means *To send the timestamp to the server, I convert it to NSString* as if it's converted to NSString, then it doesn't match your Realm object, which is an NSDate `chat.timeStamp = [NSDate date];` so how does that work. I know you answered your own question but it just seems like there's a lot of unnecessary work going on. Just use the date as a date instead of converting it to strings and back.

Comment: The server needs a time that is sent over the network. How do you send a NSDate object over a network? Either as an integer or as a string of characters indicating the time, in both ways, NSDate object needs to be translated to an integer or string. I use NSString class to finally convert the content as an array of characters to send them over the network.

Comment: The assumption is your server is Realm because well, it's a server and it supports NSDate (Swift Date) objects directly so those don't need to be formatted as a string to store them in Realm. If you are using some other server *in addition to Realm* it may require another format, but that was not specified in the question. As you have discovered, formatting a date to a string looses accuracy which makes it hard to do date comparisons with NSDate objects. You may want to consider storing the date as a double in realm so it will always match up.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but the server has nothing to do with Realm in this case, the Realm is used locally in my app. If you see the tags, you'll see iOS objective-c and Realm which gives you strong indication about Realm in an app rather than on a server. Anyway, thanks for your time to post more questions for more understanding.

Comment: Understood and thank you for the clarification - sorry didn't get that sooner, otherwise I definitely had the answer. Glad you discovered it! Speaking of clarification for future readers, ObjC does not indicate anything about how or where Realm is being used. Whether it be a local Realm or a cloud based *Realm Object Server* it can be accessed via ObjC or Swift. The Realm API is [RealmSwift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it seems that converting NSString time with format “YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS” to NSDate loses some info or accuracy.
As a consequence, the original NSDate object stored in the database doesn’t match with the one converted from NSString. So instead of assigning timeStamp with current time like this: [NSDate date], I recreate a new NSDate object with format “YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS” like this:

```c
- (NSDate*) timeStampNowWithFormat: (NSString*) format {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat: format];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    NSString *stringDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];

    return [dateFormat dateFromString: stringDate];
}

// ...
// ...

RLMChatMessage *chat = [[RLMChatMessage alloc] init];
chat.chatFrom = from;
chat.chatTo = to;
chat.timeStamp = [self timeStampNowWithFormat: @"YYYYMMddHHmmssSSS"];

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock: ^{
      [realm addObject: chat];
}];
```

Bottomline, once you convert NSDate object to NSString and then recreate a new NSDate from that NSString, both NSDate objects aren't equal anymore if time accuracy is smaller than milliseconds (i.e. microseconds).
It took me more than a day to figure that out.